# NGINX - 404 errors after caching static (CSS/JS) files

Tags: nginx, caching, http-status-code-404, cache-control

I am trying to setup nginx to cache my static files, such as jpg, jpeg, css and js.

The following is what my nginx.conf (not nginx.conf.default) looks like

```
events {}
http {

 server {
    listen       3000;
    # listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;
    # Set the SSL header only for HTTPS requests.
    if ($scheme = "https") {
        set $ssl_header SSL;
    }
    error_page 401 = @error401;
    client_max_body_size 1000M;

    # Expire rules for static content
    location / {
        # HTTPS header.
        proxy_set_header        X-Proto $ssl_header;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        Client-IP $remote_addr;

        # Redirection host.
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:300x;

     }

      location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|css|js)$ {
         expires 1d;
         access_log off;
         add_header Cache-Control "public";
      }
```

I have then tried to add the following to cache:

```
        location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|css|js)$ {
        expires 1d;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }
```

I get 404 errors for all my CSS & JS files. My JPG and JPEG files get cached. I have tired adding in the root directory here, and the in location \ {} block. This does not seem to make a difference.

I have tried many different configurations - I just want to know how to cache my css & js files!

For reference: this is the location block from my nginx.conf.default file:

```
        location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        }
```

I have tried adding the root in the server block, no luck